# facebook - App Detail Page - error trying to upload a cover image

Tags: facebook, image, cover

I am trying to finish creating a Facebook Application. As you may recall FB requests many different images of specific sizes. For some reason I am not able to upload the cover image (800x150 pixels). I have tried various files but I always receive the error "The image you are trying to upload are invalid. It may be corrupt, of wrong file format or wrong size."

Can anyone help explain why I am having difficulty with this file?

Thanks!

Comment: And what format are you attempting to upload?

Comment: I've tried bmp, jpg and gif.

Comment: Hm. My best suggestion would be to file a bug into Facebook (and it appears that you [aren't the only one](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/309669652464377?browse=search_5056b7d20254f7723726184) to run into this issue)

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis Facebook system closed this bug, because it doesn't have much requests and send us here.

Comment: I've experienced this bug and added to the growing list of developers who are complaining to FB about it.  They should reopen the bug report!